# Can I interpolate the result of json_encode directly into JavaScript code, or do I have to use JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

I'm doing some extensive testing to learn how PHP and JS variables, objects, arrays etc can be passed to one another successfully.  There's a lot of confusing questions / answers on this subject.

As far as my testing has shown, I can create a variety of PHP objects:

```php
$testarray = ["this", "is", "me"];
$testobject = (object) array("this"=>"that", "is"=>"was", "me"=>"him");
$teststring = "this is me";
$testnum = 9758.25;
```

and then I can pass them through `json_encode()` (still in PHP)

```php
echo '<script>
    var testarray = '.json_encode($testarray).';
    var testobject = '.json_encode($testobject).';
    var teststring = '.json_encode($teststring).';
    var testnum = '.json_encode($testnum).';
</script>';
```

and when run, this results in:

```html
<script>
    var testarray = ["this","is","me"];
    var testobject = {"this":"that","is":"was","me":"him"};
    var teststring = "this is me";
    var testnum = 9758.25;
</script>
```

I just want to confirm that this result is, and always will be, perfectly valid JavaScript?  I can't see anything wrong with it, yet some sources recommend the use of `JSON.parse()`.  Is this needed in this context?

I know that if an array or object in JS was passed through `JSON.stringify()`, I'd have to parse it.

I also know that to send objects or arrays from JS to PHP, I'd have to use `JSON.stringify()` and `json_decode()` to make them valid, but it seems that `json_encode()` results in valid JS without having to use `JSON.parse()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is valid, because JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript object literal syntax. Therefore if you inject JSON-encoded text into generated JS code in the way you've shown then it behaves as an object literal, just as if you'd written it there by hand.

`JSON.parse` would be required if you were receiving a string containing JSON-encoded text into a JavaScript variable (e.g. as the result of an AJAX request) and needed to convert it from a string into a usable object.

Answer (score 1):

You might think direct interpolation is enough… but there is one nasty corner case: [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#prototype_setter).

```js
var obj0 = {"__proto__": {"a": 5}};
var obj1 = JSON.parse('{"__proto__": {"a": 5}}');

console.log(obj0.a);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj0) === Object.prototype);

console.log(obj1.a);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1) === Object.prototype);
```

In an object literal, a `"__proto__":` key is required to set the prototype of the object being constructed, unless it is written as `["__proto__"]:`; this rule is suppressed when parsing JSON.  This is specified in [ECMA-262 13th Ed., §13.2.5.5, 4th variant](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#prod-N8qwXXqo).

You may never run into this problem if your JSON objects are always fixed, class-like structures, but if you ever use JSON objects to represent arbitrary key-value mappings, this may be a nasty surprise for you.

So the *really* safe way to serialize JSON into JavaScript source code would be to encode the string twice into a string literal, and parse that literal on the JS side:

```js
var testarray = JSON.parse(<?=json_encode(json_encode($testarray)); ?>);
```

Surprisingly, this technique can also come with [some performance benefits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff4fgQxPaO0).  The JavaScript grammar is sufficiently complicated that it can actually pay off to defer parsing of the object literal to runtime, in order to be able to use the much simpler and more performant JSON parser.  But as always, performance can vary over engines, versions and amount of data, and is hardly guaranteed.  Worry about correctness first, and performance second.